# passing user input in url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to pass the user inputs to the url.
My CourseController action is:

```
public ActionResult Parameter(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
       //some operations

            return View();
    }
```

I get the start and end time from the user in my view.
I want to see the url like this: Course/Parameter/start=userinput && end=userinput
Any help would be appreciated.

```
My model is:
      public class MachineSql{

       public List<Machines> SqlAccessParameter(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connstr);
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("DateRange",myConnection);
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@SP_startDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startDate;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@SP_endDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = endDate;

        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;

        DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dSet);

        myConnection.Close();

        List<Machines> machinePost = new List<Machines>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dSet.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            Machines mac = new Machines();
            mac.AutoKey = (int)row["AUTOKEY"];
            mac.MachineGroup = (string)row["MACHINEGROUP"];
            mac.Duration = (int)row["DURATION"];
            mac.StartDate = (DateTime)row["STARTTIME"];
            mac.EndDate = (DateTime)row["ENDTIME"];
            machinePost.Add(mac);
        }
        return machinePost;
    }}
```

Comment: When you say "I get the start and end from the user in my view" do you mean it's submitted using a form?

Comment: @tomasmcguinness yes,it is submitted using a form like this:          @using(ajax.beginform('ActionName','ControllerName'))

Comment: Why do you want the values passed via the URL?

Comment: Because I need to create a chart which uses json data. My aim is drawing a pie chart that shows working duration in a specific date range based on user input ( start time and end time). Chart uses url like:      dataSource:
        {

        transport:
     {
        read:
          {
           url: "Machines/Parameter",//My parameter action needs two parameter start and end date and I cannot show here.
           dataType: "json",
 }  },

Comment: If you invoke the URL with start and end parameters, MVC will automatically use them in your Parameter action.

Comment: I do not know how can I invoke them. My model as above

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the Ajax helper it's easy to add url parameters:

```
@using(ajax.beginform('Parameter',
                      'Course', 
                       //here is how you add url params
                       new { 
                             start = @Model.StartDate, 
                             end = @Model.EndDate  
                           } 
                       // Any ajax actions needed such as HyypMethod,
                       // OnSuccess, etc...
                       new AjaxOptions
                           {
                              //options here 
                           }, 
                       ))
```

This will give you a URL that looks like:

```
Course/Parameter?start=userinput&end=userinput
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you put two fields in the form called `start` and `end` and they should be part of the form that gets submitted to that controller method. ASP.NET MVC will automatically convert the values to DateTime when the route matches to that controller method.

If you are using jQuery ajax, then pass in by setting `data` to:

```
{
    start: value,
    end: value
}
```

And set `dataType` to "json".

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for details.